# Update cell value from within VBA to show user that Sub is running

Tags: excel, vba

This has been asked before but i have tried all the suggestions without success. I am running a VB for Excel subroutine that is controlled by user input read from the spreadsheet and that loops to recalculate values in memory within the subroutine. I have a line that outputs the iteration number to a cell for the user to see the progress and verify it is running properly. The cell updates for a few iterations (usual 4) and then ceases to show progress even though the routine will eventually proceed to completion at which time the cell finally updates. The current procedure may run 600-700 iterations to reach a converged solution.

Comment: excel-vba is very different from VB.NET.  Whatever you are using, please remove the other tag

Comment: When the demand on memory gets too high, Excel stops responding,  The only way to do it, in sheet, is to slow the process down at each loop to allow Excel to update the screen.  But this is counter intuitive as we want it to run as quick as possible.

Comment: Please realize with the code below you are slowing down your code, to show something.  Just want to make sure you are aware of the consequences.  It may be more important to show progress than to finish the code as quick as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way in my opinion to show the progress is to create UserForm. Below you'll find VBA code you should place in this UserForm. Just insert there 1 button and one caption - it should works. Try :)

In a module:

```
Sub UserFormTest()

UserForm1.Show

End Sub
```

In a UserForm:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim r As Integer

For r = 2 To 10000
    'Your code goes here
    Call Aktual(r)
    Timeout 0.01

Next r
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Unload Me

End Sub



Private Sub Aktual(intProgres As Integer)

Label1.Caption = "Progress " & intProgres


End Sub


Sub Timeout(seconds As Double)
Start_Time = Timer
Do
DoEvents

Loop Until (Timer + 1000 - Start_Time) >= seconds
End Sub
```